# floppy drive not working properly in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, floppy

I have been trying to get a computer sorted for my dad to backup all his floppy disks. I have been able to get the drive recognised but each time I click on the icon it says it is unable to mount as no media detected.

I have tried using the following terminal command:

```
udisks --mount /dev/fd
```

this displays the following message

```
device file /dev/fd is not a block device: resource temporarily unavailable
```

any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently on Lubuntu 12.04, and published this [guide on my website](http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/floppydiscs.html).

I have included the relevant information below, hopefully it should work for you on 10.04.

### How to Mount & Access Floppy Discs Using Ubuntu

- First open a terminal and use the command `gksudo gedit /etc/group`
- Then find the `floppy` group and add your username next to it, then
  save the file.
- Next open your Package Manager and install `fdutils`.
  This can   also be done from a terminal using `sudo apt-get install fdutils`.
- Then open a terminal and use the command `udisks --mount /dev/fd0` to
  mount the floppy.
- Then open your file manager & navigate to `/media/floppy0` to read or
  write files on the floppy disc.
- When you have finished using the floppy use the command `udisks --unmount /dev/fd0` to unmount the floppy.